# Android NDK java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: findLibrary returned null when Multidex enabled

Tags: android, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror, android-multidex

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load LPROCR from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.vehicleappraisalmanager-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.vehicleappraisalmanager-2, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

I am facing this critical error when multidex enabled. If multidex disable then .so file successfully linked and code working fine. but when multidex enabled getting unstisfiedLinkError.

here my code to load so file

```
 static {
        System.loadLibrary("LPROCR");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the class in which you are loading the library is under correct package.

Answer (score 0):

I found good solution regarding unsatisfiedlinkError when multidex enabled.
I copy .so file folder from jniLibs and paste to app/build/intermediates/jinLibs folder then rebuild app and build apk. Then application working fine.

[image]

Comment: intermediates are generated files. This should not be edited. It will crash if you install in other environment

Comment: Never do like this!